# Forcibly manipulating eigenvalues

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, vectors

If eigenvalues of a matrix A are c1 and c2. Can I multiply or do any operations with the matrix A with something to manipulate the eigenvalues c1 and c2 to a desired value ?

Answer (score 2):

Choose corresponding eigenvectors $v_1$ and $v_2$. Let $(\cdot,\cdot)$ be any scalar product with respect to which $v_1$ and $v_2$ are orthogonal to each other and both have norm one. Then define
$$
A(s,t) = A + s(\cdot,v_1)v_1 + t(\cdot,v_2)v_2.
$$
Then $A(s,t)v_1 = (c_1 + s)v_1$ and $A(s,t)v_2 = (c_2+t)v_2$. Hence $c_1+s$ and $c_2+t$ are eigenvalues of $A(s,t)$.

---

To find such a scalar product, let $U = \operatorname{span}\{v_1,v_2\}$. Then every vector $v$ can be written as $x = \lambda_1v_1+\lambda_2v_2 + w$ with $\lambda_1,\lambda_2\in\mathbb R$ and $w\in U^\perp$. For $x = \lambda_1v_1+\lambda_2v_2 + w$ and $y = \mu_1v_1+\mu_2v_2 + z$ define
$$
(x,y) := \lambda_1\mu_1 + \lambda_2\mu_2 + \langle w,z\rangle,
$$
where $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ is the standard scalar product. Then $(\cdot,\cdot)$ is a scalar product as desired.

Comment: It's also worth mentioning that $A+cI$ has eigenvalues $c+c_1$ and $c+c_2$, although this may be a special case of your example.

Comment: @Math1000 It seems to me that OP wanted to manipulate both eigenvalues independently of each other. That's how I understood the question.